# Subsonic - My base class to accommodate different model classes and repository instances

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I want to have a baseclass that will assign a DataGridView's datasource property.

I am using the ActiveRecord approach so all my code generated classes are of IActiveRecord.

IRepository needs my class to instantiate it.

I cannot seem to get this to work

What I want to do is something like this..

```
IActiveRecord GridObject;

public void SetupGrid()
{
db = new MyDB();
repo = new Repo<GridObject>(db);
DataGridView.DataSource = repo.GetAll();
}
```

This does not compile.

Any tips?

Comment: What is the name of the table you want to get data from in your database?

Comment: All of them. I am creating a WinForms project and I have a base form with a SetupGrid method.  I want to be able to set GridObject to the relevant table/class and then SetupGrid to take that and bind to a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to compile:

```
        public void SetupGrid<T>() where T : class, new()
        {
            var db = new MyApp.MyDB();
            IRepository<T> repo = new SubSonicRepository<T>(db);
            dgvGrid.DataSource = repo.GetAll();

        }
```